# Issue with connecting LinkedIn API using cURL

Tags: ssl, curl, linkedin-api, laravel-10, laravel-socialite

I trying to integrate LinkedIn API with our project. I am using [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/socialite) for integration.

After user allows permission to app, I am getting the auth code to call next API to fetch User information. Here the process is getting this error : **curl (28) ssl connection timeout**

Getting error on this API URL only : api.linkedin.com

Please attached output via command line access [curl CLI output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI8TM.png)

I have tried using different TLS version while executing curl request, but getting same response.

Comment: The TCP connectivity works but the server never responds to the TLS client hello. Looks like a network problem, some intercepting firewall  or similar. Has nothing to do with the program.